# How do I animate something using only CSS3?

Tags: css, animation

Does somebody know how I can make the solution in the link using in only CSS3.

http://1drv.ms/1IoT7Ln.

My problem. For example animation №2 (from left to right). Circle has property: "overflow: hidden", so how can the paper show out of this circle? I try to use "position: absolute" and "position: fixed", but I can not animate this properly

Many thanks.

Comment: reword your question and description, I can't understand anything

Comment: and your link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Heres a rough working concept of the how the animation could work, basically its about animating the element that will appear moving to the viewer and also animating an invisible parent element with overflow:hidden set

```
 <div class="circle">
   <div class="overflow">
     <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/rgeLsy93/